# Formatting a table in Google Doc using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Doc comprising a table with 3 columns containing first names, with lots of rows. How can I format the column widths and row heights to match a template for printing name labels?

I tried this but it won't work - what's missing?

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
// needs something to specify it's a table?
doc.setColumnWidth(1,20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the table before modifying it.

It will depend on how your data is set up, but one thing that you could try is to get all the tables inside a [`Document`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html).

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var tables = body.getTables();

  Logger.log(tables);

  for(var i =0; i< tables.length; i++){
    var table = tables[i];

    table.setColumnWidth(1, 20);
  }  

}
```

First get the `Document` with [`getActiveDocument()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getactivedocument) and after that the [`Body`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html#getbody).

With the `Body` there is a method to get all the tables with [`getTables()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body.html#gettables). That would give you an array of [`Table`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table.html). Inside the class there are several method that you can use to make your table as you want. Without more indications on how do you want your table to end up is up to you what methods to use in the `Table` class.

Comment: Hey Raserhin, Thanks so much that's really helpful, I will try it shortly!

Comment: Hi Peter, if an answer here in Stack has solved your question remember to upvote/accept so other people will identify it as a solution. Refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).